# SSIS data transformation with web service call in script task - need to multi-thread

Tags: multithreading, ssis

I am familiar with SSIS for basic tasks, but in this case I am looking for some guidance around calling a web service in multiple threads. I have a large record set coming through my data flow, and for each record I need to call out to a web service and retrieve a value based on existing data in the row. The value returned from the web service is then stored in the row and sent to output. I have this working fine now, but it performs the operation row-by-agonizing-row, which takes far to long. I would like to have my script component that calls the web service called in a multi-threaded manner so I am making dozens of web service calls simultaneously - which the web service can handle. Any pointers to the correct approach greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [Balanced Data Distributor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj191628.aspx). It is designed for situations like this. Similar in concept to Tab's suggestion of a Conditional Split but instead of you guessing at how to equally distribute the load, the BDD will detect backpressure in outputs 1 and 2 and throttle the rows sent to it until the jamb clears or until output 3 becomes equally clogged

- [BDD video](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/dn912438)
- [BDD for SQL Server 2008/2008 R2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4123)
- [BDD for SQL Server 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30147)

Comment: That looks promising, I'll give it a try, thanks billinkc and Tab.

Comment: Nice find.  I didn't know about this because it didn't ship with SSIS 2008R2, which is where my shop is languishing currently.   Nice that they made a 2008 version as an add-on.

Comment: @TabAlleman It's unfortunate that it doesn't ship with the boxed product at any level. Many organizations are loathe to install additional software even if MS supports it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a conditional split to separate your data into multiple dataflow threads and put a call to the webservice on each of the threads.

You can't do it internally in a single script component.   A script component receives one row at a time, and can't hold a row in memory and get the next row.

EDIT:   I have verified Bill's comment, that a script component can be asynchronous.   Here is the MSDN link describing this process for SSIS 2008R2:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136133(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: "You can't do it internally in a single script component" is inaccurate. The default Script Component is Synchronous and thus, 1 row in is 1 row out but you can change that to an Asynchronous method and make it 1 row in, N rows out or N rows in and 1 row out depending on your business needs.